# my cloth animation isn't working properly!

Tags: cloth-simulation

Can someone help me with my cloth animation?[image]

Comment: This is the link to the file: https://pasteall.org/media/9/0/90eedbf0f361be141f82fe27c02a9b54.blend

Answer (score 1):

this is NOT a solution, but some hints and hopefully a way to get better results:

1. collision objects and object (cloth) shouldn't intersect when you start the simulation: (this isn't possible in real world and the simulation will be weird if it does)

[image]

-> your park bench does intersect your cloth

2. higher quality steps increase the quality of cloth simulation a lot ...but of course increase the calculation time for it a lot too...

so i deleted the collision for your bench, and raised to 30 the quality level...and i got:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But do you know a solution with the bench?

Comment: You could animate the „sitting down“, and render just the sitting.